# DeviceKit Pod interfering with my function

Tags: ios, swift, function, device

I am using the pod DeviceKit to check what type of device my app is running on and then execute the specific function for the layout. For the iPhone 5 series/type of phones I am adding in a scroll view in one of my vc's. The vc is embedded in nav controller with a large title.

Any reason why the pod would cause the function to not work.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import DeviceKit


let device = Device()
```

Inside the viewDidLoad:

```
if device == .iPhone5s {
scrollView()
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

Not inside viewDidLoad(), just the function to setup the scroll view

```
    func scrollView() {

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        scrollView.contentSize.height = 800
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        //x,w,t,b
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

For some reason when I have tested the app, it works without devicekit checking which device it is and just being their originally.

Is there any way to fix this and make it able to work with DeviceKit??

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? what is it doing/not doing that you dont want?

Comment: It is not doing what I have set it to do which is when you scroll down, the large title collapses in to a small one and when u scroll up, reach the top and continue scrolling, it starts to drag down the large nav bar title as if it were a table view. It doesn't do this. I have tested it without the device kit and it works. @Scriptable

Comment: ok, that could be a few things. can I ask why you are adding a scrollview for iPhoneX only? you shouldn't need to do that, there will probably be an easier, more efficient way of doing what you want

Comment: Well its for an iPhone 5 sorry let me change that. its because the iphone 5 has too small a screen for what i need. @Scriptable

Comment: I can see your issue, I'll have a play around and see if can come up with a solution later, I dont have time now. hopefully someone will come along before then with a solution

Comment: Thanks for the help, will be back quite a while later. Hoping to hear from you @Scriptable